# Angularjs formatting a postgres timestamp from django app

Tags: python, django, angularjs, postgresql

I have a timestamp I need to display in my app like: `3:21PM`.

My Django/python code sets the object like this:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I can access this timestamp in angular by using:

```
{{message.timestamp}}
```

This gives me the entire timestamp which is formatted exactly like this:

```
2014 - 11 - 14  23:59:13 +0300
```

Since I want my timestamp to look like `3:21PM` this won't work! What I tried doing was creating a filter (in filters.js):

```
  .
  filter('asDate', function () {
    return function (input) {
      return new Date(input);
    }});
```

With the filter in place, I should in theory be able to access all of Angular's various timestamp formats in my tags like so:

```
{{ message.timestamp | asDate | date:"shortTime" }}
```

This would be perfect, except it's not working - in my app it displays:

```
NaN:NaNPM
```

So after this I went back to my filter and tried logging `input` to the console, and it shows up as I pasted earlier, so I'm just stuck here. I even tried removing the whitespace using some regex:

```
input.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

This returned `2014-11-1423:59:13+0300` which I don't think will work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it, it's actually not where I set the timestamp object in my models, it's where I define how it's returned to json...this was how I was formatting it previously:

```
return self.timestamp.strftime("%Y - %m - %d  %H:%M:%S +0300")
```

The new format (ISO8061 which angular understands):

```
return self.timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0300")
```

Now I don't need a filter either, and I just use my tag as before:

```
{{ message.timestamp | date:"shortTime" }}
```

This gave me the desired `3:21PM` looking timestamps!